# Is there any way to make a row of tiles work with GL_QUAD_STRIP?

Tags: opengl

If I want to draw a row of 2D square tiles for a game, the obvious way is to use GL_QUADS and specify 4 vertex and texture coordinates for each tile.  But since this is a row of square tiles, the last two coordinates of each square are the first two of the next one over, which sounds like exactly what GL_QUAD_STRIP is designed for.  You end up not having to repeat all the inner vertices.

The problem comes when you try to apply a texture.  You've already bound texture coordinates to the vertices when you drew them as the "end" of a quad, but when you want to reuse the last two as the beginning of the next quad, you need to reassign new texture coordinates to them unless the tile you're using is directly adjacent to the tile that the previous tile used on your tileset texture.

Is there any way to make this work?  Or do you just have to stick with GL_QUADS and specify all the inner vertices twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Later versions of OpenGL introduced a way to restart a primitive while drawing from a vertex array. What you do is specifying a special, dummy element index which instead of refering to a  element in the vertex array indicates the beginning of a new primitive chain, like a quad strip: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Primitive_Restart</s>

However if you want to make your tiles independently textured then they *don't* share vertices. A vertex is not just a position, it's also the texture coordinates and other attributes assigned to it. So actually you're not drawing a quad strip (which shares vertices) but independent quads.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it, but there's no *useful* way to do it. That is, there isn't a way to do it that doesn't add more indices. And doing it would effectively just be turning your `GL_QUAD_STRIP` into `GL_QUADS`.

So I would advise you to just stick with `GL_QUADS`.

Comment: How about using glPrimitiveRestart?

Comment: @datenwolf: My point still stands, since will make the index data bigger. You'd have 4 indices, then a restart, then 4 indices again. With GL_QUADS, you just have each individual quad of 4 indices. You get nothing out of it except bigger index data.

Comment: Ah, I see. OP want's to give each tile a different part of a texture atlas. Well, then a quad strip is not the right way to go.